# Reset upload file input field after submission

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-directive, mean-stack

I'm working on an AngularJS project that involves uploading a file to S3 via a form. Everything works (I can upload the file, the file name on the input changes from "No file chosen" to whatever the name of the file is) except after a successful upload I want to reset the upload file field back to its original values (Displaying: "No file chosen". Im having trouble doing this even after reseting $scope.file to null. I have the upload file input as a directive here

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('file', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, el, attrs){

     scope.$watch('file', function(newValue, oldValue){
        console.log(newValue);
        console.log(scope.file);
     });

     el.on('change', function(event){
       var files = event.target.files;
       var file = files[0];
       scope.file = file;
    });
  }
};
});
```

I have a watcher set up so I can check whether or not the value is changing when I set it to null via the controller, which it is, so I'm unsure on what I can do to reset the input field back to default values. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//After upload in your call back function in directive

```
$(el).val('')
```

You can directly clear value of file upload control

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, this solved my issue. It's always something simple that's the issue haha.